# Do subdomains have an impact on a root domain?

Tags: seo, google-analytics, google-search-console

My domain discountbox.in was performing well on the Google search engine. A couple of days back we launched the blog and forum on the subdomain discuss.discountbox.in and within the next 2 days we were kind of penalized heavily. What could be the cause of this? Do subdomains have an impact on the primary domain?

Comment: What makes you think you were "penalized heavily"?

Comment: We used to get 1500 visit everyday which went down to 100 visits a day. There is no change in the structure or data on the site. Only change is we launched our blog at subdomain 3-4 days back.